# Using .9.png image in background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have created bg3.9.png image following this tutorial

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

but when i put it in my drable folder and try to use it then it gives error in the project
please see the image.[image]

The code in main.xml file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bg3">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:columnWidth="65dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please guide me on what i have done wrong ?

Comment: after making the image .9.png have you removed the non png image?

Comment: I've had this too. Adding a nine patch image to the drawable folder causes Eclipse not to be able to build your project. Try removing the file, do a clean build and then try adding the nine patch back in. Sometimes, I've had to re-create the nine patch image from scratch.

Comment: yes i have removed non png images from the drawable folder but still same problem :(and now by creating new.9.png image from scratch is working but now my grid view is not showing up on full screen please see the edit code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to see the name in your screenshot but it doesn't look like your image is named bg.9.png, it looks like it has a three letter name (wheras your code references @drawable/bg)

It should not be named bg3.9.png, it should be named bg.9.png

Comment: Using the full image URL (http://i.stack.imgur.com/IFlIf.jpg) you can see that the image is indeed called `bg3.9.png`.

Comment: sorry for posting wrong image name now i have edited it please tell me now what to do ?

Comment: Question marked correct so I guess you have solved the problem.  Otherwise I suggest that you now clean the project (Project > Clean) then rebuild it (Project > Build) (if the project is not being built automatically).